# WMQ self-signed SSL mutual authentication fails when QM has special character

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, mq

I have two queue manager servers running on two boxes. QM1 has a sender channel defined , and QM2 has a receiver channel with the same name.
I have created self signed certificate for each QM , extracted and added the public part of each certificate to the other QM's key db. Altered each channel to use CipherSpec TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US.

This setup works perfectly fine, if QM names don't contain any special character. If name of the sender QM is A_QM and the other one is B_QM , the sender channel never comes up and is in RETRYING state.

while creating self-signed certificate I am using label ibmwebspheremq*a_qm*
 in case of A_QM and ibmwebspheremq*qm1* when the queue manager is QM1. Similarly when adding the public part of the certificate I am preserving the other QM's label. This is the only difference in the whole setup.

Is there any restriction in defining QM names if I want to configure SSL or TLS ?

Comment: Take a look at A_QM and B_QM queue manager error logs. You might find useful information there.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the cause?

Answer (score 3):

I had no trouble creating a pair of QMgrs and channels as described and getting them to run:

```
[mqm@rhel6base scripts]$ runmqsc A_QM
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2014.
Starting MQSC for queue manager A_QM.


dis chs(*) all
     1 : dis chs(*) all
AMQ8417: Display Channel Status details.
   CHANNEL(A_QM.B_QM)                      CHLTYPE(SDR)
   BATCHES(0)                              BATCHSZ(50)
   BUFSRCVD(1)                             BUFSSENT(1)
   BYTSRCVD(268)                           BYTSSENT(268)
   CHSTADA(2015-04-01)                     CHSTATI(10.57.43)
   COMPHDR(NONE,NONE)                      COMPMSG(NONE,NONE)
   COMPRATE(0,0)                           COMPTIME(0,0)
   CONNAME(127.0.0.1(3115))                CURLUWID(0C031C5501020010)
   CURMSGS(0)                              CURRENT
   CURSEQNO(0)                             EXITTIME(0,0)
   HBINT(300)                              INDOUBT(NO)
   JOBNAME(0000130700000001)               LOCLADDR(127.0.0.1(53145))
   LONGRTS(999999999)                      LSTLUWID(0000000000000000)
   LSTMSGDA( )                             LSTMSGTI( )
   LSTSEQNO(0)                             MCASTAT(RUNNING)
   MONCHL(OFF)                             MSGS(0)
   NETTIME(0,0)                            NPMSPEED(FAST)
   RQMNAME(B_QM)                           SHORTRTS(10)
   SSLCERTI(CN=rhel6base.ioptconsulting.com)
   SSLKEYDA( )                             SSLKEYTI( )
   SSLPEER(SERIALNUMBER=55:1C:06:B2,CN=rhel6base.ioptconsulting.com)
   SSLRKEYS(0)                             STATUS(RUNNING)
   STOPREQ(NO)                             SUBSTATE(MQGET)
   XBATCHSZ(0,0)                           XMITQ(B_QM)
   XQTIME(0,0)                             RVERSION(08000001)
   RPRODUCT(MQMM)                       

[mqm@rhel6base ssl]$ runmqakm -cert -list -db key.kdb -stashed
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!   ibmwebspheremqb_qm
*-  ibmwebspheremqa_qm
[mqm@rhel6base ssl]$ runmqakm -cert -list -db ../../B_QM/ssl/key.kdb -stashed
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!   ibmwebspheremq_a_qm
*-  ibmwebspheremqb_qm
[mqm@rhel6base ssl]$
```

**REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)**
The most likely cause for the behavior you are seeing is not issuing refresh security or restarting the QMgrs after updating their keystores. For example:

```
echo "REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)" | runmqsc A_QM
echo "REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)" | runmqsc B_QM
```

or

```
endmqm -i A_QM; strmqm A_QM
endmqm -i B_QM; strmqm B_QM
```

One aspect of security for the keystore is that there is only ever one version of it in memory at a time. If it were possible for one channel to have one version and another channel to have another version, it would become impossible to determine which was the "right" one in order to detect tampering. So when the KDB is updated, the refresh security command causes the QMgr to stop all running TLS channels, dump the KDB from memory, and reload the KDB when one of the channels starts.

*(MQ doesn't use SSL, by the way, never has. It uses TLS with SSL ciphers and now that SSL itself is broken, best to get used to saying TLS because that will help to remember to use TLS ciphers exclusively going forward.)*

So after updating the KDB if you did not run the refresh, it is likely that the refresh was not done and the QMgr doesn't yet know about the newly added certificate for the remote QMgr.

**When SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) is *not* optional**
Another common problem with TLS is a misunderstanding of `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)`.  Many people believe that this *always* results in one-way authentication so they set `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` and then exchange certs in only one direction.  For example, QM1 has TLS channels to QM2 so obviously has its own personal certificate.  Then we try to connect A_QM to it.  We import A_QM's personal cert to QM1's KDB, refresh security everywhere, `DEF CHL(A_QM.QM1) ... SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` on both sides and try to start the channel.

The misunderstanding is that if the thing initiating the channel has a personal cert it *will* send it in all cases.  To test with `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` requires removing any personal cert from the keystore on the side initiating the connection.  Often people do not realize this and spend many hours (in some cases weeks) struggling to understand why this fails.

For your purposes always exchange the personal certs in *both* directions.

**Incomplete cert exchange**
The other common problem working with self-signed certs is when a cert is generated multiple times with the same label and/or CN value and there's a mismatch between the personal cert on one end versus the public portion on the other.  This is easily checked by viewing the cert details and checking that the fingerprint and other details match like so:

```
[mqm@rhel6base ssl]$ runmqakm -cert -details -label ibmwebspheremqb_qm -db key.kdb -stashed
Label : ibmwebspheremqb_qm
Key Size : 1024
Version : X509 V3
Serial : 551c06b2
Issuer : CN=rhel6base.ioptconsulting.com
Subject : CN=rhel6base.ioptconsulting.com
Not Before : April 1, 2015 10:54:42 AM EDT
Not After : March 31, 2016 10:54:42 AM EDT
Public Key
    30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01
    05 00 03 81 8D 00 30 81 89 02 81 81 00 DF 0F 90
    8C C2 CA D1 ED 16 E2 A8 DA E3 26 63 45 4B B2 29
    37 04 65 A1 D3 30 23 2A 67 AB 61 06 75 E1 8B 87
    D2 9A CD 38 4C 63 D6 CC AD 25 55 B3 8B BE 34 4E
    32 CB EB FE E2 5D E0 49 2F 57 AC EC 5E 79 A2 52
    F6 21 5A 5F 95 AB C4 70 C8 00 68 0B 22 32 8C 1F
    4C DB 0C D9 85 B8 06 5A 7C DA 3A 3A BE 12 C8 C1
    C0 92 5E FE 09 46 F7 E1 1F 3D 4A AA 63 F0 80 09
    3D FE E7 A4 49 5D 86 09 4C B5 0E 1E 97 02 03 01
    00 01
Public Key Type : RSA (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)
Fingerprint : SHA1 : 
    55 FC 2C 7C 00 8E A7 27 78 0D 99 AD FF 84 58 57
    BF 16 1C 62
Fingerprint : MD5 : 
    90 66 AD 5D 71 AF 75 E8 9A 4A A3 5A DB 15 CD 21
Fingerprint : SHA256 : 
    7E 43 75 25 31 ED E7 76 FA 40 87 37 F3 B2 9E 6F
    2D 55 2D 3C CB 52 60 9C 85 B2 53 F3 1C C0 D2 3C
Extensions
    AuthorityKeyIdentifier
      keyIdentifier: 8D BC 64 AF D9 12 02 34
      authorityIdentifier:
      authorityCertSerialNumber:
    SubjectKeyIdentifier
      keyIdentifier: 8D BC 64 AF D9 12 02 34
Signature Algorithm : SHA1WithRSASignature (1.2.840.113549.1.1.5)
Value
    46 D4 8A D9 62 04 CF C4 0E 23 DB 4C F9 AD 25 9B
    89 3B FD B9 4F 52 4C DE 36 96 15 92 0E 7B 03 05
    E8 85 12 AD E7 40 DB E9 4D 77 8F B7 4B CC 43 1B
    AD 6D 13 B1 2F 26 12 C8 1C 17 FE 51 A7 B7 7B EE
    80 CA 82 37 98 E1 B4 17 3A B4 CC 20 E7 4E 53 42
    C6 E1 C3 1C 54 BD DC 9A 14 86 9A 25 66 AC 11 2C
    78 A0 B5 DC 22 FE 52 62 59 27 02 DA 82 07 64 42
    38 99 8A A7 52 53 20 C3 B2 FF 8F 6D A6 A3 8F 72
Trust Status : Enabled
[mqm@rhel6base ssl]$ runmqakm -cert -details -label ibmwebspheremqb_qm -db ../../B_QM/ssl/key.kdb -stashed
Label : ibmwebspheremqb_qm
Key Size : 1024
Version : X509 V3
Serial : 551c06b2
Issuer : CN=rhel6base.ioptconsulting.com
Subject : CN=rhel6base.ioptconsulting.com
Not Before : April 1, 2015 10:54:42 AM EDT
Not After : March 31, 2016 10:54:42 AM EDT
Public Key
    30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01
    05 00 03 81 8D 00 30 81 89 02 81 81 00 DF 0F 90
    8C C2 CA D1 ED 16 E2 A8 DA E3 26 63 45 4B B2 29
    37 04 65 A1 D3 30 23 2A 67 AB 61 06 75 E1 8B 87
    D2 9A CD 38 4C 63 D6 CC AD 25 55 B3 8B BE 34 4E
    32 CB EB FE E2 5D E0 49 2F 57 AC EC 5E 79 A2 52
    F6 21 5A 5F 95 AB C4 70 C8 00 68 0B 22 32 8C 1F
    4C DB 0C D9 85 B8 06 5A 7C DA 3A 3A BE 12 C8 C1
    C0 92 5E FE 09 46 F7 E1 1F 3D 4A AA 63 F0 80 09
    3D FE E7 A4 49 5D 86 09 4C B5 0E 1E 97 02 03 01
    00 01
Public Key Type : RSA (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)
Fingerprint : SHA1 : 
    55 FC 2C 7C 00 8E A7 27 78 0D 99 AD FF 84 58 57
    BF 16 1C 62
Fingerprint : MD5 : 
    90 66 AD 5D 71 AF 75 E8 9A 4A A3 5A DB 15 CD 21
Fingerprint : SHA256 : 
    7E 43 75 25 31 ED E7 76 FA 40 87 37 F3 B2 9E 6F
    2D 55 2D 3C CB 52 60 9C 85 B2 53 F3 1C C0 D2 3C
Extensions
    AuthorityKeyIdentifier
      keyIdentifier: 8D BC 64 AF D9 12 02 34
      authorityIdentifier:
      authorityCertSerialNumber:
    SubjectKeyIdentifier
      keyIdentifier: 8D BC 64 AF D9 12 02 34
Signature Algorithm : SHA1WithRSASignature (1.2.840.113549.1.1.5)
Value
    46 D4 8A D9 62 04 CF C4 0E 23 DB 4C F9 AD 25 9B
    89 3B FD B9 4F 52 4C DE 36 96 15 92 0E 7B 03 05
    E8 85 12 AD E7 40 DB E9 4D 77 8F B7 4B CC 43 1B
    AD 6D 13 B1 2F 26 12 C8 1C 17 FE 51 A7 B7 7B EE
    80 CA 82 37 98 E1 B4 17 3A B4 CC 20 E7 4E 53 42
    C6 E1 C3 1C 54 BD DC 9A 14 86 9A 25 66 AC 11 2C
    78 A0 B5 DC 22 FE 52 62 59 27 02 DA 82 07 64 42
    38 99 8A A7 52 53 20 C3 B2 FF 8F 6D A6 A3 8F 72
Trust Status : Enabled
```

**Debugging**
Check the error logs.  In particular, it is good security design to give an attacker as little information as possible to always check the logs of the QMgr that is receiving the connection first.  If it has detected the error it will have detailed logs and the sending side will have sparse logs like "the remote QMgr disconnected" which doesn't reveal much to an attacker.

If the error is actually on the sending side, then it will have most detailed error messages and the receiving side will have little or none. For example, if the sending side can't find its stash file the connection isn't ever attempted and the receiving side will have no record of the event.

Finally, there is always the possibility that you may discover a bug working with GSKit and MQ, or that you are trying to use features not relevant to version of MQ that you are working on.  For this reason, it is always best to include a `dspmqver -a` in your question.  If after all of this, you still can't get it to work, please update the question with the `dspmqver -a` output and the results of your further testing.

**In summary**
To sum up:

- QMgr names like A_QM are perfectly valid.
- First make sure that the QMgrs have picked up their new KDB files after changes by restarting the QMgrs or running `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)`.
- Make sure to exchange certs in both directions every time.
- Check the error logs on both sides starting with the side receiving the connection request.
- Always include output from `dspmqver -a` when requesting help with GSKit, certs or TLS since the behavior varies by version and fix pack.

Comment: Same here T.Rob. I too was able to setup secure channels between A_QM and B_QM. Many thanks for elaborate explanation.